# Trigger slice mouseover on Google Interactive Chart

Tags: charts, interactive

I'm creating a custom legend for my Google pie chart because I need a little more control.

I would like my legend to interact with the chart exactly the same as the default legend.  I can add listeners to my legend rows that select the corresponding slice like:

```
myChart.setSelection([{row: selectedIdx]);
```

That causes the slice to select as if I'd clicked the slice, that is to say, it renders the hard line a few pixels away from the slice.

Which is okay, but what I really want is to replicate the slice mouseover, i.e. just the "highlight" of the slice.

I thought the chart might be listening for a mouseover and then examining the event to determine which slice to highlight, so I attached an onmouseover listener to it.  That seemed correct because when I moused over a pie slice, the even passed in was:

```
Object {row: 1, column: null}
```

In my legend row listener, I then triggered the chart mouseover and passed in the same event:

```
google.visualization.events.trigger(myChart, 'onmouseover', {row: selectedIndex, column: null});
```

But that didn't work. I also tried by explicitly creating a JS object as well as using parseInt on the selected index.  In the Firefox debugger, both things (actual mouseover, legend trigger) looked exactly the same from the point of view of the listener, but only the actual mouseover caused the slice to highlight.

Which leaves me stumped.  Anyone have an idea how to do this?  Ideally, I'm looking for something like:

```
var slice = myChart.getSlice(someIndex);
slice.setHighlighted();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is not possible with Google Charts. However you can write code to explode the slice rather than highlighting. It does the same thing from a user's perspective IMO.